# wait for DownloadFileAsync in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

"next" is appearing before download completes. i know it's a Async so will execute and release the control. Is there any way to wait for download before running the next command.

```
If System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem = True Then
            MsgBox("64 bit")
            myurl = my64biturl
            myfilename = "java-64.exe"
            download = New WebClient
            download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(myurl), "java.exe")
            MsgBox("next")

        Else
            MsgBox("32-bit")
        End If
```

Comment: You need to `await` the function call. `await download.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(myurl), "java.exe")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working. Used the download_DownloadFileCompleted section to start another download or perform next action.